# How to make an item "draggable" using html?

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to just use html to make an item draggable? (not just classifying an element as draggable)

Comment: with out jquery \ javascript ?

Comment: yes,  but I have read the answers and now know that I need to use javascript/jquery.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Draggable Enlightenment

Unfortunately, [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is a **feeble presentational language** which merely gives us the functionality to describe structure of text-based data in a document. It has no way of adding marvelous interactions such as 'draggability'.

Luckily, [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) allowed such interactions and it's **widespread uptake** in web browsers caused developers to rejoice! However browsers implemented JavaScript in a variety of ways, causing [heartache and distress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IE6) for debuggers and testers.

Alas, help is at hand. [JavaScript frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_frameworks) have become **the solution** to the misery of inconsistent implementations and developers can again add interactions to their pages.

Arguably **the finest of these** frameworks goes by the name of [jQuery](http://jquery.com) and can be found here. Others go by the name of [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/) and [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/).

Get to know one of them closely and [draggable](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.7.1/Draggable) **enlightenment will be yours**.

Answer (score 7):

No, you'll need to use javascript.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is very popular javascript framework which does a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Here are the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Draggable) for their draggable component.

Answer (score 3):

Nope Javascript. Have a look at [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.6/Draggable/draggable).

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy using HTML5, then there is support for draggable elements, but it does still use javascript.

HTML5 adds a couple of extra events: ondragenter, ondrop and ondragover.

Here's an example page: http://ljouanneau.com/lab/html5/demodragdrop.html

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with javascript or jquery... so I'll have to learn it.  But thanks for the example link!

Comment: If you do go this way, I'm not sure about IE compatibility at the moment. This isn't using jQuery, it's a native way of doing things but only in modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Javascript for that.